# T-test in Python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

How do I make a t-test in Python?

```
#*-* coding: utf-8 *-*
from __future__ import division
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

x=([ 0.01082045  0.00225922  0.00022592  0.00011891  0.00525565  0.00156956])
y=([ 0.00096333  0.00019453  0.00038384  0.00058286  0.00078786])
ttest=stats.ttest_ind(x,y)
print 't-test independent', ttest
```

I get two numbers out: `t-test independent (array(1.5061708454111165), 0.1662878376677496)`

I don't know what they mean. Could you maybe help me? And what does the one "array" mean?

I have samples and two different machines. I have to compare the two methods with t-test.

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html):

> Returns:
>   `statistic` : float or array The calculated t-statistic.
>
> `pvalue` : float or array The two-tailed p-value.

That is, 1.5 is your two-tailed, standard normal Z score & .166 is the corresponding p-value.

Comment: But I just have to get one t-value? Here I got two values? I look at this webpage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_two-sample_t-test I just thought I had to just get one value (t) out like on the wikipedia webpage. There I just have a t-value ... nothing with a p or anything. How do I get the t-value?

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich sounds like you're having statistics problems more than programming problems. I recommend http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dr.HenrietteB.Fröhlich: If you like, you can write `t, p = stats.ttest_ind(x,y)`.  Then `t` is the t-value.